# How can I convert object data to an array for use with bs-typeahead in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

My data looks like:

```
[
            {
                "_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d611",
                "active": true,
                "client": {
                    "_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d60e",
                    "name": "TR"
                },
                "company_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d60c",
                "createdOn": "2014-03-10T13:35:07.313Z",
                "description": "Gentle Action Application Pads",
                "dimensions": {
                    "weight": 22.4
                },
                "lot": [
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "category": "Face",
                    "msrp": 7.75
                },
                "sku": "11002",
                "unit_of_measure": "each",
                "updatedOn": "2014-03-10T13:35:07.314Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d612",
                "active": true,
                "client": {
                    "_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d60e",
                    "name": "TR"
                },
                "company_id": "531dbf8b9b9fc50000a8d60c",
                "createdOn": "2014-03-10T13:35:07.317Z",
                "description": "Skin Renewal System - Enriched (CA)",
                "dimensions": {
                    "weight": 22.4
                },
                "lot": [
                ],
                "meta": {
                    "category": "Face",
                    "msrp": 321.6
                },
                "sku": "11700CA",
                "unit_of_measure": "each",
                "updatedOn": "2014-03-10T13:35:07.318Z"
            }
        ]
```

In my view, I have:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="receivingSku" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="sku for sku in getSku($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="selectedSku()" class="form-control">
```

I need the `sku` field for each item to be in the typeahead. How can I accomplish this?

Presently, I get an error:
`Error: matches is undefined`

Comment: if you post the code that has `matches` in it, then it might be easier to find the problem

Comment: I don't have any code with `matches` in it. I assume it has something to do with the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your original array and create an array of just SKU's:

```
var skus = origArray.map(function(e) {
  return e.sku;
});
```

The new array can be used for typeahead.

*PS - I'm not very familiar with typeahead. If typeahead is capable of peeking into objects, you don't need to do this.*